# ffmpeg segment muxer causing timecode error

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to break down a single input file into 4 separate output files using segment in ffmpeg. I'm stream copying to the separate output files (the input uses the DNxHD codec, so there are no keyframe issues).

Command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c copy -r 24 -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0:0 -f segment -increment_tc 1 -segment_start_number 1 -segment_frames 360,720,1080 output_%4d.mov
```

So far the command is working well, except for timecode. There is no data / timecode stream in the output files and I'm seeing this error for each segment during processing...

> Valid timecode frame rate must be specified. Minimum value is 1

Full output:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c copy -r 24 -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0:0 -f segment -increment_tc 1 -segment_start_number 1 -segment_frames 360,720,1080 output_%4d.mov
    ffmpeg version N-94014-g80e68ce116-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
      built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
      configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
      libavutil      56. 28.100 / 56. 28.100
      libavcodec     58. 52.102 / 58. 52.102
      libavformat    58. 27.103 / 58. 27.103
      libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
      libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
      libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
      libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
      libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mov':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 537199360
        compatible_brands: qt  
        creation_time   : 2019-06-14T13:48:53.000000Z
        timecode        : 01:00:00:00
      Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 116392 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dnxhd (DNXHD) (AVdn / 0x6E645641), yuv422p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 116391 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2019-06-14T13:48:53.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
          encoder         : Avid DNxHD Codec
        Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2019-06-14T13:49:09.000000Z
          handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
          timecode        : 01:00:00:00
    [segment @ 0x7fa448001600] Opening 'output_0001.mov' for writing
    [mov @ 0x7fa448003400] Valid timecode frame rate must be specified. Minimum value is 1
    Output #0, segment, to 'output_%4d.mov':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 537199360
        compatible_brands: qt  
        timecode        : 01:00:00:00
        encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dnxhd (DNXHD) (AVdn / 0x6E645641), yuv422p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 116391 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2019-06-14T13:48:53.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
          encoder         : Avid DNxHD Codec
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [segment @ 0x7fa448001600] Opening 'output_0002.mov' for writing
    [mov @ 0x7fa449000000] Valid timecode frame rate must be specified. Minimum value is 1
    [segment @ 0x7fa448001600] Opening 'output_0003.mov' for writing
    [mov @ 0x7fa449000000] Valid timecode frame rate must be specified. Minimum value is 1
    [segment @ 0x7fa448001600] Opening 'output_0004.mov' for writing speed=73.7x    
    [mov @ 0x7fa449800c00] Valid timecode frame rate must be specified. Minimum value is 1
    frame= 1440 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:59.95 bitrate=N/A speed=72.7x    
    video:852480kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Looking at the command with full debug on, the error shows:

```
[mov @ 0x7f9d4a006800] timecode: tbc=1/0 invalid, fallback on 0/0
[mov @ 0x7f9d4a006800] Valid timecode frame rate must be specified. Minimum value is 1
```

I'm not aware of any way to set the timecode framerate as an option outside of the drawtext filter, which obviously is not relevant. Looking at this error in the [original source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/timecode.c), it appears it's specifically designed to handle issues within the drawtext filter as referenced in this [bug report](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2017-November/219172.html).

Firstly, is the command formatted correctly and secondly, is there a way to preserve the input timecode track and using the '-increment_tc 1' flag to keep it correctly set for each segment? BTW I have also tried adding '-timecode 00:00:00:00' to see if I could create a new track, but this did nothing.

Thanks

*edit...*
Here is the log to show the error when using '-map 0' instead of '-map 0:0'

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c copy -r 24 -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 -f segment -increment_tc 1 -segment_start_number 1 -segment_frames 360,720,1080 output_%4d.mov
ffmpeg version N-94014-g80e68ce116-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      56. 28.100 / 56. 28.100
  libavcodec     58. 52.102 / 58. 52.102
  libavformat    58. 27.103 / 58. 27.103
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2019-06-14T13:48:53.000000Z
    timecode        : 01:00:00:00
  Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 116392 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dnxhd (DNXHD) (AVdn / 0x6E645641), yuv422p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 116391 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-06-14T13:48:53.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Avid DNxHD Codec
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-06-14T13:49:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 01:00:00:00
[segment @ 0x7fe5d5807400] Opening 'output_0001.mov' for writing
[mov @ 0x7fe5d5802a00] Valid timecode frame rate must be specified. Minimum value is 1
Output #0, segment, to 'output_%4d.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    timecode        : 01:00:00:00
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dnxhd (DNXHD) (AVdn / 0x6E645641), yuv422p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 116391 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-06-14T13:48:53.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Avid DNxHD Codec
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-06-14T13:49:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 01:00:00:00
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Floating point exception: 8
```

Comment: This is related to segmentation. I'll take a look.

Comment: I should add that I'm using '-map 0:0' as when I leave this out or use '-map 0' I get this error message:

`Floating point exception: 8`

and the command stops without creating the output files.

Comment: Share the log for that.

Comment: Have added it above. It very much looks like its the timecode stream thats causing this crash.

Comment: Debugged - will fix this too.

Comment: Great. Are you already pushing patches for these issues?

Comment: Sent for review. Will push on Tuesday if no changes.

Comment: Pushed. Data track remux will be pushed in a couple of days but you don't need that. Skip muxing it since it won't be incremented anyway.

Comment: I'll run my test again and report back. Thank you very much for sorting this.

Comment: Tested with latest master and all working with zero errors. Amazing. Thank you so much Gyan.

Answer (score 1):

To complete this post with an answer, this issue was caused by a few bugs in ffmpeg, which have now been fixed by Gyan:

commit [2fdbeb0b8cc3b80cf45674522c4867eeb985f274](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/2fdbeb0b8cc3b80cf45674522c4867eeb985f274)

commit [91f5950f833fd48f12de769374129334f8c6b237](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/91f5950f833fd48f12de769374129334f8c6b237)